# jquery .each wwith a dynamic name / variable

Tags: jquery, variables, each

I have the following syntax:

```
 $.each(result, function(key, value){
         alert(value.first_name);
    });
```

first_name is obviously a value in the array.

what I want/need to do is something like this:

```
$.each(result, function(key, value){
var column='first_name';
             alert(value.column);
        });
```

I want to alert the value in the array that comes from a variable. this obviously fails as it sees column as an array key rather that a variable.

is this possible?

alternatively something like `alert(value[2])` will work as well

Thanks,

Comment: `value['first_name']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `value[column]` instead of `value.column`

```js
var value = {
    first_name: 'John'
  },
  column = 'first_name';

alert(value[column]);
```

For more about JavaScript object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: so simple, sorry man. Thanks for your efforts. works 100%